# Perforce VISUAL client I can install the COMMAND line but not the VISUAL client

Tags: 22.04

I tried a lot of stuff but I could only get the command line apt-get install helix-cli but not the visual client ./p4v to run any idea?

Long story I followed the following instructions,
https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-visual-client-p4v
and I did not get the VISUAL perforce to run.

But using a library wget I could install it the helix-cli with the file perforce.list
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/perforce.gpg] https://package.perforce.com/apt/ubuntu jammy release

any idea on how to get the visual client to work for ubuntu jammy?

Comment: Have you tried running `/opt/perforce/bin/p4` instead? The file is not in your current directory or home folder, so `./` won't work unless you do `cd /opt/perforce/bin`